# SQL Sum of 2 rows when 4 rows are returned

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

I'm trying to get a percent complete column in SQL for the following data. This is the results from my query.

```
work_order_no status        orderqty        complete precentcomplete
WO-000076     Approved      20.0000         9        5201725
WO-000076     Approved      20.0000         10       15605175
WO-000078     Approved      12000.0000      200      91258.3333333333
WO-000078     Approved      12000.0000      500      228145.833333333
```

What I need is a result with 2 rows. Row 1 will be WO-00076 and the percent complete. Row 2 will be WO-000078 and the percent complete. Below is the query that I am working with.

```
 Select distinct wo.work_order_no,
                wos.status_description,
                wo.order_qty as [ORDERQTY],
                p.good_tot_diff as [COMPLETE],
                (sum(p.good_tot_diff)/wo.order_qty) * 100 as [PERCENTCOMPLETE]
from wo_master as wo,
     process as p,
     wo_statuses as wos,
     so_children as soc,
     so_sales_orders as sos,
     cs_customers as csc
where wo.work_order_no = p.entry_18_data_txt
and wo.work_order_no = soc.work_order_no
and wo.wo_status_id = wos.wo_status_id
and wo.mfg_building_id = @buildid
and wos.wo_status_id = @statusid
group by wo.work_order_no, wos.status_description, wo.order_qty, p.good_tot_diff
```

So I would like the results to be like below

```
work_order_no status        orderqty        complete precentcomplete
WO-000076     Approved      20.0000         19       0.95
WO-000078     Approved      12000.0000      700      0.005
```

Comment: Why is the complete value for `WO-000076`19 insteado of `19+57`?. And also, if the quantity is 20, why do 57 in the first place??

Comment: I edited the original result to match the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you want. The complete column should not be included in the GROUP BY, and should be summed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wo.work_order_no, wos.status_description, wo.order_qty AS [ORDERQTY], SUM(p.good_tot_diff) AS [COMPLETE], (sum(p.good_tot_diff)/wo.order_qty) * 100 AS [PERCENTCOMPLETE]
FROM wo_master AS wo,
     process AS p,
     wo_statuses AS wos,
     so_children AS soc,
     so_sales_orders AS sos,
     cs_customers AS csc
WHERE wo.work_order_no = p.entry_18_data_txt
  AND wo.work_order_no = soc.work_order_no
  AND wo.wo_status_id = wos.wo_status_id
  AND wo.mfg_building_id = @buildid
  AND wos.wo_status_id = @statusid
GROUP BY wo.work_order_no,
         wos.status_description,
         wo.order_qty;
```

Comment: This pulls the data into 2 single rows, but now the issue is Complete Column and % Complete aren't calculating correctly.

Comment: Formulate your problem more concisely, without including irrelevant tables and I'll take another look at it.

Comment: I figured out my issue. However, this answered my original question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select wo.work_order_no,
    wos.status_description,
    wo.order_qty as [ORDERQTY],
    SUM(p.good_tot_diff) as [COMPLETE],
    SUM(p.good_tot_diff)/wo.order_qty as [PERCENTCOMPLETE]
from wo_master as wo,
    process as p,
    wo_statuses as wos,
    so_children as soc,
    so_sales_orders as sos,
    cs_customers as csc
where wo.work_order_no = p.entry_18_data_txt
and wo.work_order_no = soc.work_order_no
and wo.wo_status_id = wos.wo_status_id
and wo.mfg_building_id = @buildid
and wos.wo_status_id = @statusid
group by wo.work_order_no, wos.status_description, wo.order_qty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*, (COMPLETE/wo.order_qty) * 100 as [PERCENTCOMPLETE]
FROM
(
Select distinct wo.work_order_no,
                wos.status_description,
                wo.order_qty as [ORDERQTY],
                SUM(p.good_tot_diff) as [COMPLETE],
from wo_master as wo,
     process as p,
     wo_statuses as wos,
     so_children as soc,
     so_sales_orders as sos,
     cs_customers as csc
where wo.work_order_no = p.entry_18_data_txt
and wo.work_order_no = soc.work_order_no
and wo.wo_status_id = wos.wo_status_id
and wo.mfg_building_id = @buildid
and wos.wo_status_id = @statusid
group by wo.work_order_no, wos.status_description, wo.order_qty 
) A
```